# how to comfirm a client in autobahnPython

Tags: autobahn

I use autobahnPython + autobahnJs set up a chatting service.

Now I want to a function, when a client connect wamp, the member list of chatting room be updated automatically. How implement this function?

```
def onSessionOpen(self):
```

I think in onSessionOpen function add action, but I don't know how to do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be: have a dedicated PubSub topic per chat room. When a WAMP client subscribes to a "chat room topic", it'll be automatically added to the subscriber list for that chat room. The subscriptions are held in `self.factory.subscriptions[<topic URI>]`. Please note that the latter is an internal object .. not a public API. We would need to know more what else you want to do .. i.e. have an RPC to get the current subscribers on a chat room and such.

Disclaimer: I am author of WAMP, Autobahn and work for Tavendo.

Comment: <blink>@exportSub("chattingroom")
    def subscribe(self, topicUriPrefix, topicUriSuffix):
        print "someone subscribe chattingroom"

        msg = '[7,"http://example.com/event/chattingroom",{"message":"memberUpdate","member":"","caller":"server"}]'
        self.factory.onMessage(msg, False)
        
        in this function, how to use onMessage method?</blink>

Comment: You should not override onMessage .. the default implementation needs to handl the WAMP messages. If you need custom handling of publication, have a look at the example here: https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/blob/master/examples/wamp/pubsub/custom/server.py